# Is there's a way to use opencv with GPU acceleration on Google Colab?

Tags: opencv, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a Haar classifier on Colab using !opencv_traincascade. Based on the times it takes to train stage 1-5,it would take me about 3 days to finish stage 20. Is there's a way to take advantage of the GPU and speed up the training?

Answer (score 0):

You can build OpenCV with `TBB` to use `numThreads` and use the `-precalcValBufSize` `-precalcIdxBufSize` parameters. I don't think it has support for using GPU. If you have an i7 core or something, it will be much faster to use your machine.